# Xbox controller disconnecting with full battery

Tags: xbox-360

It will keep on disconnecting after about 5 minutes of me reconnecting sometimes less. I have just recently replaced the batteries and it says it has full battery anyway.

edit: The time is random as I have seen from playing today. sometimes it will stay connected for an hour sometime 2 minutes. I am not using a rechargeable battery pack, it is a regular xbox controller, it is about a year old now. Also it only seems to disconnect after I start using it. after a while it will be fine. If I leave the controller alone it does not disconnect. It also will disconnect is I move it about to much.

Comment: can you try different batteries.  because only one of two things is possible.  Your batteries are actually bad or the controller is going bad.

Comment: About "5 minutes", "sometimes less"? We need more details. I had a similar problem, and I may be able to help. I assume you're not using a rechargeable battery pack. Is your controller custom made, modded, or a themed one? How old is it? I need to know all this to be able to help.

Comment: Apolagies for not being clear, The time is random as I have seen from playing today. sometimes it will stay connected for an hour sometime 2 minutes. I am not using a rechargeable battery pack, it is a regular xbox controller, it is about a year old now.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me just get a new battery pack the one you have is probably loose or just get a new controler if you have two controlers switch battery packs

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like dirty connection(clean with dry scotch cloth). Or loose, as in try taping it tighter to the controller.(One of your mates probably has a battery pack case spare). Or ensuring it's connected firmly.

Comment: Batteries yeah?

Answer (score -1):

I have had this problem for a while now and good year tried everything as well new batteries, firmware controller update, and nothing worked. I even did the factory reset on console but still no luck. So I was looking round the other day and saw a forum post about replacing the wireless card in the Xbox One.

I managed to get one off ebay fitted yesterday and played today and OMG not one disconnect while playing. It was heaven to play and played for a good 3 hrs or so while it only would stay connected for more than 10 mins before without disconnection issues.

[image: Xbox One Wifi Card]

Comment: Hi Shaun!  That's a good idea to follow up on, would you happen to have or know what the card name, or what to search for if someone wanted to replace that controller receiver?